# Does clojure community have an equivalent of perltidy?

Tags: emacs, clojure

I have a function definition like so:

```
(defn init-globals [] (def *board-width* 15))
```

I want to be able to reformat so that it looks something like:

```
(defn init-globals []
   (def *board-width* 15))
```

I would like the formatting to be done by an intelligent agent that doesn't merely indent everything a fixed amount, or just prints one element per line etc.  This is something that perltidy does.

perltidy takes code like:

```perl
sub foo {
my $args = shift;    $a = $args->{a}; $long_var = $args->{b}; }
```

and turns it into:

```perl
sub foo {
    my $args = shift;
    $a        = $args->{a};
    $long_var = $args->{b};
}
```

Notice how it considers the "sub" defintion as a whole, and even the "=" on the last two assignments line up.  While I don't necessarily need this level of formatting, I would like something that takes a list (or more accurately, a form), that is a function with args and subexpressions, and makes it as human readable as possible.

The reason my function definition is a single line is because it's generated from a macro.  I don't want to clutter up the macro with formatting instructions (if indeed I can even do this without generating a string instead of a list) because macros are hard enough as it is.  While I can eval the list into my REPL just fine, I would also like to write the generated code to a file as if it were typed in by hand i.e something you could check into source control.

I've looked at things like (clojure.pprint/pp), and using emacs 'indent-sexp and smartparen's 'sp-indent-defun, but they don't split the output into multiple lines among other things.

I can interop with emacs/elisp commands, so if there's a way to do it with emacs, that would work too.

Comment: def inside other forms is usually a bad idea

Comment: @noisesmith I think the outer def here is supposed to be a macro emitting the list (def ...) and the backquote got lost in translation.

Comment: just use any proper clojure code editor from the following list: `[:emacs]` and it'll do it for you ;)

Answer (score 4):

If this is what you want to do, then I'd suggest simply printing your generated code (or however you want to write it to a file) and then throwing [cljfmt](https://github.com/weavejester/cljfmt) at it.

There exist tools such as bbloom's [Fipp](https://github.com/brandonbloom/fipp) which can do similar code pretty-printing from inside a Clojure instance, but to the best of my knowledge cljfmt does a better job.

I think that it's worth considering *why* you are attempting to save macroexpanded code, since the cost of macroexpansion is nominal and it would be considered better practice to generate code as-needed rather than to generate code, save it, and then handle it as if it had been hand-written. Retaining code generation also means that your codebase is more flexible in that you can just tweak the generator and reload the namespaces involved rather than having to regenerate the generated code, and then reformatting and recompile that.

Comment: Thank you.  These are just the kind of things I was looking for.  I am testing them now.  I also found 'elisp-format' which seems to do a pretty good job (but you have to use clomacs to interop into elisp).  I will try to post my final solution when I'm done.

Comment: Regarding, why I'm doing this.  Really, I'm just learning about macros.  If this were for real, I would check in just the macros and gen it each time.  But it will really help me if I can see what the gen'd code looks like -- macro code is hard to read.  Also, I might work for a shop that doesn't allow gen'd code, but I could gen it and then pretend I wrote it by hand!  I know, dumb idea, I'm just trying to explore the possibilities of what works/doesn't work with macros.

Answer (score 2):

There is [lispy](https://github.com/abo-abo/lispy) - my extension with short bindings for general
LISP programming.

It supports any LISP, and even has Clojure inline eval, inline args, inline doc, and goto-symbol via
CIDER.

It also has a naive multi-lining shortcut that does exactly what you want for this
particular function.

With `lispy-mode` on, you need to position your cursor either on the paren before `defn` or after
the paren at the end of the line. Then press <kbd>M</kbd> to format an expression over multiple
lines.

To format it back into a single line, press <kbd>O</kbd>.

To improve a badly formatted expression like this one:

```clojure
(defn init-globals[](def *board-width* 15
                      )
  )
```

navigate to a proper paren and press <kbd>i</kbd>.

If you happen not to be fully satisfied with a result of particular <kbd>M</kbd>, you
can quickly fix it manually, using <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>l</kbd> and
<kbd>f</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd> for by-paren navigation.